# Running Integration Test project with dependencies on a parent project via Docker

Tags: java, docker, integration-testing

I'm new to this site (although Ive used it many times for information!) And have decided to ask a question as me and my colleagues are stuck with Docker as were new to the tech.

I have an integration-test project written in Java, which tests various parts of the system. Ive setup a maven goal for the project which is ran by running:

> mvn clean verify -P integraion-test

This works fine when running from the command line, but were looking to expand the process by containerizing it using Docker. The problem is that the integration testing project depends on some jars from the project were trying to test such as DAO and API related things. In my POM.xml I have

```
<parent>
 <groupId>com.fleet</groupId>
 <artifactId>fleet-parent</artifactId>
 <version>1.0.0</version>
</parent>
```

which will pull the dependencies down from the parent so that they can be used inside the integration-test project.

However, when i build my dockerfile using

> docker build -t integration-tests .

I get the following error:

> The project com.kinesisfleet.integration:running-integration-tests:0.1 (/integration-test/pom.xml) has 1 error
> [ERROR]     Non-resolvable parent POM for com.fleet.integration:running-integration-tests:0.1: Could not find artifact com.fleet:fleet-parent:pom:1.0.0 in central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2) and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM.

This is my Dockerfile:

> FROM maven
>
> ADD . /integration-test
>
> WORKDIR /integration-test
>
> RUN  mvn clean install
>
> CMD  mvn verify -P integration-test

Is there anyway of getting the jars from the parent into my integration-test project so they can be used?

Can i use the COPY command to copy jars from my local repo inside my project?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to stackoverflow!

Maven tries to download the parent-pom from the public maven-repository and doesn't find it there. Do you have a private maven-repository in your company and do you upload your parent-pom to that private repository?

If yes, just copy your maven settings.xml into your image. In that settings.xml you should configure your private repository.